# Selected image clears on submit javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML form with a drop-down menu. I have the images displaying on selection from the menu, however when the submit button is clicked the form resets and the selected image is cleared. Is there a way to stop this from happening?

```js
// Enter your JavaScript for the solution here...
let memeImg = document.querySelector("#meme-image");
let selectedImg = document.querySelector(".meme-display>img");
let topTxt = document.querySelector("#meme-top-text");
let enteredTxtTop = document.querySelector(".top-text");
let bottomTxt = document.querySelector("#meme-bottom-text");
let enteredBottomTxt = document.querySelector(".bottom-text");
//display img
memeImg.addEventListener("change", function() {
  if (memeImg.value == "fry-meme") {
    selectedImg.src = "img/fry-meme.png";
  } else if (memeImg.value == "one-does-not-simply-meme") {
    selectedImg.src = "img/one-does-not-simply-meme.png";
  } else if (memeImg.value == "most-interesting-man-meme") {
    selectedImg.src = "img/most-interesting-man-meme.png";
  } else {
    error.classList.remove("hidden");
    document.querySelector(".error").innerHTML +=
      "<p>Please select an image from list</p>";
  }
});

//top text

topTxt.addEventListener("oninput", function(evt) {
  if (topTxt.value != "") {
    enteredTxtTop.innerHTML = topTxt.value;
  } else {
    error.classList.remove("hidden");
    document.querySelector(".error").innerHTML +=
      "<p>Please enter charachters in top text </p>";
  }
});

//bottom text

bottomTxt.addEventListener("oninput", function(evt) {
  if (bottomTxt.value != "") {
    enteredBottomTxt.innerHTML = bottomTxt.value;
  } else {
    error.classList.remove("hidden");
    document.querySelector(".error").innerHTML +=
      "<p>Please enter charachters in bottom text </p>";
  }
});

//submit

document.querySelector(".meme-form").addEventListener("submit", function(evt) {
  document.querySelector(".memedisplay> img") = selectedImg;
});
```

```css
/* simple layout */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  grid-template-areas: "sidebar content";
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  width: 20em;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
}


/* styles */

.error {
  color: red;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.form-control {
  width: 20rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.form-control>label {
  display: block;
}

.form-control>input,
.form-control>select {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 1px;
  height: 2rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
}

.form-control>input[type=submit],
.form-control>input[type=reset] {
  width: 25%;
}


/* content layout */

.meme-display {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

.meme-display>p {
  width: 550px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.meme-display>p.bottom-text {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 3;
}

.meme-display>p.top-text {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.meme-display>img {
  width: 550px;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1/4;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Assignment 1 - Meme Generator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:700" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Meme Generator</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
      <section class="sidebar">
        <h2>Meme Options</h2>
        <div class="error"></div>
        <form class="meme-form">
          <div class="form-control">
            <label for="meme-image">Meme Image</label>
            <select name="memeImage" id="meme-image">
              <option value="">Choose an image...</option>
              <option value="fry-meme">Fry Meme</option>
              <option value="one-does-not-simply-meme">
                One Does Not Simply Meme
              </option>
              <option value="most-interesting-man-meme">
                Most Interesting Man
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-control">
            <label for="meme-top-text">Top Text</label>
            <input type="text" name="memeTopText" id="meme-top-text" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-control">
            <label for="meme-bottom-text">Bottom Text</label>
            <input type="text" name="memeBottomText" id="meme-bottom-text" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-control">
            <input type="submit" value="Generate" />
            <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </section>
      <section class="content">
        <h2>Generated Meme</h2>
        <div class="meme-display">
          <p class="top-text"></p>
          <p class="bottom-text"></p>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/550x300?text=Choose+an+image+from+the+dropdown" alt="Placeholder Image" />
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
  </div>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/psyduckMethinks/txw6Lvdp/5/) of my work so far.

Answer (score 0):

**Add `evt.preventDefault();` in the for sudmit handler function, like this:**

```js
document.querySelector(".meme-form").addEventListener("submit", function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    document.querySelector(".memedisplay> img") = selectedImg;
});
```

*`evt.preventDefault();` will prevent the default behavior of form submission on button click which used to trigger the page reload.*

[**Docs:** `Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

[**Complete Code on CodePen**](https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/KKvzVwa)